# Plot3D of multiple functions

Tags: plotting, mesh

I am trying to combine 3D plots of different functions. Usually, this works:

```
Plot3D[{f1[x,y],f2[x,y]},{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1}]
```

However, I am encountering a weird phenomenon. Sometimes, when I plot f1 and f2 separately and combine the graphs with Show[...], all is fine. But if use Plot3D[{f1,f2}...] then the graph is messed up.

What is going on ? I am guessing that Plot3D[] with multiple functions tries to decide on a compromise mesh that will work for all arguments. But in the following example where both functions basically have the same values, I don’t understand how it can fail.

Here is an example of this problem on Mathematica 11.2 (MacOS 10.12.6). I solve the Burgers equation either exactly or numerically (examples from the documentation).

```
BurgersEquation1 = D[u[x,t],t] + u[x,t] D[u[x,t],x] == 0.1 D[u[x,t],{x,2}];
InitialCondition1 = u[x, 0] == Piecewise[{{1, x < 0}}];
f1 = DSolveValue[{BurgersEquation1, InitialCondition1}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
f2 = NDSolveValue[{BurgersEquation1, InitialCondition1, u[-2, t] == 1, u[2, t] == 0},
                     u, {x, -2, 2}, {t, 0, 1}];
   (* the extra boundary conditions for f2 help with the numerical
      computation but it’s not relevant to this question *)
g1=Plot3D[Evaluate[f1], {t, 0, 1}, {x, -2, 2}]
g2=Plot3D[f2[x,t], {t, 0, 1}, {x, -2, 2}]
```

The output ares two nice graphics that I cannot distinguish by eye:

[image: sharp edge graph]

But this one is bad:

```
Plot3D[{Evaluate[f1],f2[x,t]},{t, 0, 1}, {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image: round edge on the exact solution]

However, as one could expect, combining the two good ones with show gives anothe good one:

```
Show[{g1,g2}]
```

[image: sharp edges on both]

What is going on ? And what should I do to secure the output from Plot3D[{f1,f2}] ?

PS1. I added some colors and meshes options to generate the pictures above and make them clearer, but it does not change the core problem.

PS2. A better zoom on the problem. I have shifted the exact solution above in the Plot3D[{f1,f2}] and the exact one is really badly meshed:

[image: zoom on the problem]

```
                       ------- Better example -----
```

It’s really not a numeric vs exact problem. Look at the output of this:

```
  f[t_,x_]:=1/(1 + (E^(-2.5(t - 2 x)) (1 + Erf[(1.5811 x)/Sqrt[t]]))/(1 + Erf[(1.5811(t - x))/Sqrt[t]]));
  Plot3D[{0, f[t,x]}, {t, 0, .05}, {x, -0.2, 0.2},
          PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, PlotTheme -> "ZMesh »]
```

[image: two functions is bad]

and compare to the output of this:

```
  Plot3D[f[t,x], {t, 0, .05}, {x, -0.2, 0.2},
          PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, PlotTheme -> "ZMesh"]
```

[image: one function is good]

Plotting the zero function next to another one should not alter the graph....

Comment: Since a symbolic and numeric solution to a DE will always be different, I'm not surprised that there are slight differences in the `Plot` and I expect the glaring color shifts are just making this more obvious. `Plot3D[f1-f2[x,t],{t, 0, 1}, {x, -2, 2}]` to inspect the difference of the two solutions. Include a `,PlotRange->{-.01,.3}` option to `Plot` to see a much larger error near (0,0).

Comment: @Bill: You might have missed the point. Look at the arrow I added on the 2nd graphic. The exact solution (the green one) is mis-meshed near the origin when it is plotted with something else, but not when it is plotted alone on the 3rd graph. I am adding a zoom so you can see the problem better.

Comment: Hm. I think i see your problem but I cannot reproduce it with version 11.3 on macos 10.13.4.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: that would be good news if I just need to update. Try the simpler example I just found and added at the end.

Comment: Ah, now I see it. Seems to happen only if the problematic function is not the first in the list... Very strange. I think it is related to the fact that `1/(1 + (E^(-2.5 (t - 2 x)) (1 + Erf[(1.5811 x)/Sqrt[t]]))/(1 + 
       Erf[(1.5811 (t - x))/Sqrt[t]])) /. t -> 0` returns the wrong result `1/(1 + E^(5.` x))`.

Comment: Plotting for `{t, 0.0000000001, .05}` does not show this problem anymore. Still it is strange that this happens only if a second function is present.